# Force display of taskbar button text instead of window in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I often have a large number of Excel workbooks open, and need to navigate between them. If I have enough workbooks open, they are displayed by title text when I mouse over the combined taskbar button, which makes it very easy to determine which one to select; however, if only a few are open, they are only represented by a little screenshot of the open sheet, which is completely useless as a means of differentiation. Is there any way to force the display of titles only, not screenshots, regardless of how many Excel instances are open?

Comment: You can right-click the icon to get a list of recent files. Although you can't see which of them you have open, if you click one, it will either switch to it, or if not open, open that for you. Can't seem to find a better way. You can also hover the preview if you left-click and after 1 second, you get a popup with the title, and the window also is brought to the front.

Comment: One option is WIN+TAB. This will show you all windows with thumbnails, but their caption is also visible. Switching to the correct Excel sheet should be easy here. (ALT-TAB also works, but win+tab respects multiple displays, where alt-tab doesnt)

Comment: Thanks—that's a helpful workaround.

Comment: Also, you can consider having your taskbar setup to always show labels, never combine. With few windows open, you can just see the first 5-10 characters of the title in excel anyway. If you have multiple monitors, you can choose to have your main monitor combine, but your second monitor not. Native in windows.